# ORACLE SQL Query to fetch all table names IN DB whereever given value is treated as PK

Tags: oracle, primary-key

Just want to know is this possible.
Say that if i have value 'X' and iam sure that this is referenced in some other tables as PK value but not sure about exactly which table is that, so i would like to know the list of those tables.

Pseudo query of above what i mentioned

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE <<ATLEAST ONE OF THE TABLE ROW PK VALUE IS MATCHING EQUAL TO 'X'>>;
```

Comment: Is the value `X` an actual value?  Like `Mike` is a value entered in some table and it's in a column that's a primary key?  Or do you mean `X` is a column name?  Like `Mike` is a column name for some table somewhere and it's a PK?

Comment: Hi bassrek, X is a value and it is not PK in this table but in some other table

Comment: OK, well, it's possible, but it's not native functionality. You'd need to take a look at something like this: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/find_pkeys.php which shows you how to query for all your PKs (you could refine based on datatype, perhaps).  You throw that into a cursor, then dynamically create a query looking for `X` in each table.column within the cursor.  It is very ugly and inefficient and I wouldn't recommend doing this on a prod environment.